# Grouped UITableView with custom cell in Editing Mode

Tags: iphone, uitableview

i have issue in UITable view. i am using UITableView and Custom cell view  with Grouped style like this

[image]

my problem is when editing my table view its showing like this [image]

but i need to hide the thumbnail image while editing table view like this [image]

I tried while editing table view `[cell.imageviews setHidden:YES]` but its doesn't work please any body help me if already Question is in Stack-overflow  please give me the reference link or any other suggestion?

** UPDATE**

here my code for  cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CustomCellidentifier = @"IListCell";
IListCell *cell = (IListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CustomCellidentifier];
if(cell == nil) {
    
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IListCell" owner:self options:nil];
    cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
        }

  if (self.tableview.isEditing) {
    [cell.photoImageView setHidden:YES];
    }

cell.titleTextField.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[artAlbumList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

return cell;
 }
```

IListCell Is subclass of `UITableViewCelll` the custom cell  created using XIB file this is my xib file [image]

Comment: post your code in that method.

Comment: Post code for : IListCell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test your code with break point
set breakpoint at `setEditing:editing`

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
   if(editing == YES){
       photoImageView.hidden = YES
   }
   else
   { 
     photoImageView.hidden = NO; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the thumbnail images are not actually inside the table view cells. Keep in mind that you must not create any direct subviews of the UITableViewCell; all subviews must be subviews of the UITableViewCell's `contentView`.

The easiest way to hide the image automatically while editing is probably to override your custom cell class's `setEditing:animated:`. Be sure to call `super`! Hide the image or show it depending on the first (BOOL) parameter.

Comment: so what can i do for  hide that image?